# Method Not Allowed (POST): /property/like/

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

My form submit keeps throwing this error Method Not Allowed (POST): /property/like/

```
     <form action="{% url 'property:like-post' %}" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}

        <input type="hidden" name="property_id" value="{{obj.id}}">

        {% if request.user not in obj.liked.all %}
          <button class="btn love-badge btn-raised btn-wave btn-icon btn-rounded mb-2 white" type="submit"> <i class="mdi mdi-heart-outline"></i></button>
        {% else %}
          <button class="btn love-badge btn-raised btn-wave btn-icon btn-rounded mb-2 teal" type="submit"> <i class="mdi mdi-heart-outline"></i></button>
        {% endif %}
    </form>
```

view.py

```py
def like_property(request):
    user = request.user

    if request.method == 'POST':
        property_id = request.POST.get('property_id')
        property_obj = Property.objects.get(id=property_id)

        if user in property_obj.liked.all():
            property_obj.liked.remove(user)
        else:
            property_obj.liked.add(user)

        like, created = Like.objects.get_or_create(user=user, property_id=property_id)

        if not created:
            if like.value == 'Like':
                like.value == 'Unlike'
            else:
                like.value = 'Like'

        like.save()

    return redirect('property:list')
```

urls.py

```
app_name = 'property'

urlpatterns = [
    path('like/', views.like_property, name='like-post'),
]
```

Any insight on anything I'm doing wrong would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Where does your property_id come from? There is nothing captured in the url, i.e. you have no <int:property_id> in your urls.py?

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('like/<int:property_id>', views.like_property, name='like-post'),
]
```

Then in views:

```
def like_property(request, property_id):
...
```